# Question on modifying Helm's search (helm-ag or similar tools)

Tags: helm, helm-ag

I'd like to do the following when I search

```
- find symbol in a project 
- add restrictions (options) 
  - to narrow to files that matches a pattern (--include) 
  - to narrow to files that doesn't match a pattern (--exclude)
  - to change the base directory (it can be project root or any directory that a user wants)
```

I've used helm-grep and helm-ag

They allow those changes, but mostly I need to restart the search so that helm can prompt me for those options.
For example, if I start out with project-root, and I decide to narrow the search to a directory, I need to start over the search from the start and specify the directory I want to search.

I suspect the dynamic search options that I describe can be done.
Because it seems to be similar to the ability to go from `helm-swoop to helm-multiswoop`.
Difference is that I want to go back and forth and need to keep more states (such as include files, exclude files and such)

My guess is that, you can store a context (eg include files, search query, root directory for search) then issue an updated command with the stored context.

Since it seems to take me a while to figure out that it's indeed doable, I thought I would ask first if this is indeed doable.

Especially, I'm not sure how `context` should be implemented in elisp. (elisp has notion of buffer-local and such, and I am not quite familiar with the concepts)
I guess my work would be easier if I can figure out how `helm's session`(?) can be stored.

Of course this will be easy if helm-ag or helm-grep implementation supports this type of operation.
But even if they don't, helm itself might support it.

I wanted to ask this is doable by helm itself.